# View display in listview xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I need to show my views in listview. I did it on wpf in this way:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CommissionVMs}" BorderBrush="White">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:Commission/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

CommissionVMs is my collection of viewModels and Commission is view to be displayed. So how can I do this on xamarin forms?

Comment: Have you looked at how you can do it? Because it is basically the same in Xamarin.Forms. So are you having trouble? If yes, with what?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be specific when you ask questions, showing your (related!) code, what the problem is, what you tried to fix it, what you got and what you expected instead. In your case, please also include other resources you've read/tried because it sounds like a fairly generic thing to do.

Comment: As far as I understand I have troubles with viewModel binding to view. In wpf I had an element that contained my view and I linked my viewModel to view automaticly. But in xamarin.forms there isn't such binding. I can't do it in this way at least. And I can't understand what I should change to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I just needed to create my view as ViewCell and then display it in listView just like usual container.
So the issue was just in wrong container.